# Spring+HibernateDAO DAO bean not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've faced the issue that I cannot defeat.

I have a Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {

@Autowired
private HibernateUserDAO hibernateUserDAO;

//Here is some further code
```

Here is my snippet of HibernateDAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class HibernateUserDAO implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session getCurrentSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override

public void addUser(User user) {
    getCurrentSession().save(user);
}
```

Here is my spring config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="ua.macko"/>
       <mvc:annotation-driven/>
       <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources"/>
       <tx:annotation-driven/>

       <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"/>
              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
              <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog"/>
              <property name="username" value="****"/>
              <property name="password" value="****"/>
              <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
              <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
       </bean>






       <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
              <property name="formatters">
                     <set>
                            <ref bean="userFormatter"/>
                     </set>
              </property>

       </bean>

       <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
              <property name="annotatedClasses">
                     <list>
                            <value>ua.macko.entity.User</value>
                     </list>
              </property>
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                     <props>
                            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                     </props>
              </property>
       </bean>

       <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
       </bean>

</beans>
```

The problem is I've got the error:

```
Could not autowire field: private ua.macko.dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserDAO ua.macko.controller.AdminController.hibernateUserDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ua.macko.dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

If I remove tx:annotation-driven from spring configuration, I can launch the project, but when I try to perform addUser() Method then I've got an error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

How can I solve this? How is tx:annotation:driven can influence the bean autowiring?

Comment: can you post complete stacktrace of exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the Transactional annotation to your class, Spring will create a proxy for that class to do the transaction logic. If the bean implements an interface, Spring will create a JDK based proxy which implements all interfaces of the bean. Thus the type of the proxy is in your case `UserDAO` and not `HibernateUserDAO`.

There are 2 solutions:

1:
Change the field type of the autowired field to the interface:

```
@Autowired
private UserDAO hibernateUserDAO;
```

2: Configure Spring to use CGLIB based proxies. Those proxies extend the bean class and so they have the same type as the bean class itself. This can be done either with the following annotation and it's attribute, if you use that:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Or if you use XML configuration for the transaction manager:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

You can read more about the proxies etc. in the Spring docu: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `@Transactional`, an autoproxy generator will implement The Interface. so you need to autowire to the interface not the implementation.

```
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO hibernateUserDAO;
```